# How to know what config string I can use in application.ini in zend_application?

Tags: php, zend-framework

such as:

```
[production]
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH
```

How to know "resources.frontController.moduleDirectory" is a valid config item

Comment: Many of the valid config keys are listed on [one page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) of the ZF manual.

Comment: @JohnFlatness thank you. How can I mark you as valid answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All keys that start with `resources.someResourceName` will be passed to the corresponding resource. Each individual resource is responsible for dealing with those options.

The Zend Framework manual includes [a page](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html) that lists configuration keys for the built-in resources. While that page should probably cover most things, it's not necessarily exhaustive.

If the manual doesn't list the keys for the resource you're looking for, it's often a good assumption that the same options you can programmatically pass to a Zend Framework component are also keys for its associated resource. As a last resort, looking in the resource's code (which will be in the `Zend/Application/Resource` folder for built-in resources) should at least give you an idea what keys are valid.

Of course, you can also [write your own resource plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.theory-of-operation.html#zend.application.theory-of-operation.resources), and you'd be in control of what configuration keys they accept.

Comment: Please note that in addition to resources you can also have parameters for anything that has a setter in your bootstrap. For exaple, if you have a setFoo($foo) method you could then have foo = bar in your config file and "bar" will be passed to the setFoo method.